# Gerar um ficheiro minificado para cada ficheiro dentro de uma pasta

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulpjs

Configurei a seguinte task para gerar um ficheiro minificado:

```
gulp.task('frontend-js', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
        'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
        'src/AppBundle/Resources/public/Frontend/js/main.js'
    ])
        .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('web/js'));
});
```

O script acima gera um único ficheiro minificado.

Quero gerar um ficheiro minificado para cada ficheiro `.js` que existir dentro da pasta `src/AppBundle/Resources/public/Frontend/js/`, exceto o ficheiro `main.js` que foi incluído na task acima.

Por exemplo:

> src/AppBundle/Resources/public/Frontend/js/teste.js => web/js/teste.min.js
>   src/AppBundle/Resources/public/Frontend/js/teste2.js => web/js/teste2.min.js
>   src/AppBundle/Resources/public/Frontend/js/teste3.js => web/js/teste3.min.js

É possível fazer isso com o gulp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim. Basta que o seu atributo `src` exclua este arquivo em específico. De uma maneira simples, isso poderia se resolver com a seguinte *task*:

```
gulp.task('js', function(){
    return gulp.src([
            'src/AppBundle/Resources/public/Frontend/js/*.js',
            '!src/AppBundle/Resources/public/Frontend/js/main.js'
         ])
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('web/js'))
});
```

Perceba a negação (`!`) no atributo `src`, onde eu digo que, após eu ter selecionado todos os arquivos `.js`, um deve ser removido. Veja também que removi o seu método `concat()`, para evitar concatenar todos os arquivos em um só. Por fim, note que esta *task* só verifica arquivos diretamente dentro da pasta `/js`. Arquivos dentro de pastas internas à esta pasta devem ser buscados com o seletor `**`